# Как сделать выборку строк только с одинаковыми парами значений полей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Есть вот такая модель (специально пишу в очень упрощенном виде, сути это не меняет):

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    count = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Как мне выбрать товары с одинаковым названием и ценой?

Answer (score 2):

Получаем дубликаты:

```
duplicates = Product.objects.values('name', 'price').annotate(cnt=Count('id')).filter(cnt__gt=1)
```

Список продуктов:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
    name__in=[item['name'] for item in duplicates], 
    price__in=[item['price'] for item in duplicates]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать F-выражение, [подробнее](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/).

```
from django.db.models import F
equals = Product.objects.filter(name=F('price'))
```

Comment: Не совсем уверен, что ваш ответ об этом. Я хочу выбрать не такие товары, у которых price==name, а, грубо говоря, дубли. У которых совпадают название и цена.